# Choosing random numbers in a 2D arrays

Tags: c++

I want to pick 2 numbers randomly in a 2D array[4][2].
My 2D array stock (x, y) and I want to randomly choose
between two coordinates.

I tried the following algorithm, but it doesn't work:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define DEBUG
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int nb_aleatoire(int min, int max)
{
    return min + (int)(rand() / (RAND_MAX + 0.001) *(max - min + 1));
}

int main(void)
{
    int lab[4][2] = {
        { 1, 4 },
        { 2, 4 },
        { 3, 8 }
    };

    int alea;
    int x;
    int y;
    int i, j;

    /*On initialise le générateur de nombres aléatoires. */
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    rand();

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        printf("(%d, %d)\n", rand(lab[i][i + 1]), rand(lab[i][i + 1]));
    }

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is to shuffle the array and pick the first two elements. If you only need two, then getting a pair of random indexes is more efficient, if you need the elements randomized, a shuffle is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

[`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) doesn't take any arguments.

This could be done by:

```cpp
size_t max_x = std::size(lab);
size_t max_y = std::size(lab[0]);

size_t random_x = rand() % max_x;
size_t random_y = rand() % max_y;

auto random_value = lab[random_x][random_y];
```

[`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) was introduced in C++17, so for older versions, the array size must be calculated like this:

```cpp
size_t max_x = sizeof(lab) / sizeof(lab[0]);
size_t max_y = sizeof(lab[0]) / sizeof(lab[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

```
int lab[4][2] = {
    { 1, 4 },
    { 2, 4 },
    { 3, 8 },
};
```

Your 4 element array only has 3 members.

Howe about this instead:

```
int lab[4][2] = {
    { 1, 4 },
    { 2, 4 },
    { 3, 8 },
    { 4, 9 }
};
```

As for this line:

```
printf("(%d, %d)\n", rand(lab[i][i + 1]), rand(lab[i][i + 1]));
```

I'm not sure how it compiles since `rand` doesn't take any parameters. (Are you really compiling as C?). `rand` returns a value between 0 and RAND_MAX, which is typically 32767.  To clamp the range of `rand`, use a modulo `%` operator.

```
int c1 = rand() % 4;
int c2 = rand() % 4;
int r1 = rand() % 2;
int r2 = rand() % 2;
printf("(%d, %d)\n", lab[c1][r1], lab[c2][r2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this `printf` is a problem:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", rand(lab[i][i + 1]), rand(lab[i][i + 1]));
}
```

If `i` was updated to exceed `0`, e.g. `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)`. You will start encounter buffer overrun issues in the second value of your lab array. If `i` were to increase further, you will encoutner buffer overrun issues in the second value of your lab array. Like others have mention, the computation of the lab[] value is irrelevant since `rand()` does not take an argument for input, so, what you're doing with the `lab` array will, ultimately, be ignored.

The actual intention is not clear. Perhaps a random x value followed by a random y value?

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    int j = srand() % 3;
    int k = srand() % 3;
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", lab[j][0], lab[k][1]);
}
```

From a data science perspective, it doesn't make sense. You had 3 unique x values but 2 unique y values. The above could generate 6 random combinations.

Since you preloaded your lab with 3 coordinates, perhaps you merely want to randomly select one of those coordinates random?

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    int p = srand() % 3;
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", lab[p][0], lab[p][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But the problem is that I want to choose a random coordinates in my 2D array

For example:

Array[row][col] = { {4, 5},
{6, 3} };

So, (4, 5) and (6, 3) are coordinates (x, y)
that I want to randomly choose between the two.

Comment: This post should be added to the original question, as it expands on it